# Are there measurements I can take on my server's power supply to estimate its health?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, failure

My [server's PSU](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getdocument.aspx?docname=c04284861) is about 7 years old, and it's running 24/7 at about 30% load.

While I think that it will last some more years, I would like, if possible, to anticipate its failure, since often it results in further damage to the electronics components.

Are there measurements I can take on its output rails (12 V, 5 V, 3.3 V) to anticipate imminent issues?

I could monitor voltage and ripple, but are they indicative of ageing? Since I have an UPS powering the server, I could in theory correlate the readings with the overall load, if needed.

Comment: Increased output ripple is probably a good indication that the capacitors are drying out. Do you know how much you had when it was brand new?

Comment: @winny I haven't started taking any measurement yet, but I can use the ATX specifications as thresholds.

Comment: Yes, but are you just just that as your cutoff when to replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, the main sources of failure in PCs power supplies are: electrolytic capacitors, fans and power semiconductors, so it makes sense that your condition monitoring focuses on them:

**Electrolytic capacitors:** As mentioned in the comments, check for increase in voltage ripple.

**Fans:** Measure (if you can) fan’s current consumption and rpms.

**Power semiconductors:** It’s hard to do condition monitoring from input-output measurements only, so if you can check the temperature (as close as possible to the power semiconductor). An increase can point to a degradation of that power semiconductor’s solder layers.